# Could not determine server status in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

Trying to set up RSelenium as described in this article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-up-rselenium-for-r/

When I try to set up the driver in my R code, I get the following error message:

```
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome") : Could not determine server status.
```

I try to check the server log but all I see is:

```
$stderr
[1] ""

$stdout
[1] ""
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Test wether this works: go to the chromedriver directory (to find it: `print(binman::app_dir("chromedriver"))`), go to the last version or the version you're using, then delete the LICENSE.chromedriver file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) i.e. [***v114.0.5735.90***](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.90/) and the minimal code block will be:

```
# R program to demonstrate RSelenium

# load the required packages
library(Rselenium)

# start the Selenium server
rdriver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
            port = 2122L,
            chromever  = "114.0.5735.199",
            )

# creating a client object and opening the browser
obj <- rdriver$client

# navigate to the url
obj$navigate("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")

# closing the browser
obj$close()
```